# Qt Overloaded Mouse Event Handler not being called when mouse is clicked

Tags: qt, events, mouse, qgraphicsview, qwidget

I am writing a chess program using my own class called chessCV, which is derived from `QGraphicsView`, and then I am adding it to my MainWindow class as a member.  I cannot seem to get the program to execute the `MousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)` function, which I overloaded.  It never gets called.  I thought maybe it had to do with the way that I inherited from `QGraphicsView`, but I tried overloading the `MousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)` in the  MainWindow class, and that is not being called either.  I am completely stumped.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Post the `chessCV::MousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)` declaration in the header file, we can't help you without seeing code.

Comment: did you find a solution? i'm facing the same issue with deriving from QWidget

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to overload `QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)`, the m should not be capitalized.